# What's the point in apt-key add?

Tags: apt

I've noticed that when installing packages from `apt`, sometimes we do something like:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
```

If I understand correctly, what we do here is we go and fetch a GPG public key from `https://download.../gpg`, and put it in `/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg`. Then, we tell apt - "when you download packages from `https://download.docker.com/...` verify that these packages are signed by the private key belonging to this public key".

So I don't quite understand: if we trust that it is Docker on the other side of `https://download.docker.com/..`  - and we do since this is where we get the public key from - then why do we need to verify packages coming from there with a gpg key?

Sounds like a self-signed certificate to me.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ThomasWard, ok, so let's say in this case that you want me to install you malicious software. So you give me your own GPG key AND your own debian package signed with this GPG key. So how does GPG helps us here?

Comment: @YoavKlein I've summarized my two comments together into one answer, which goes into depth about MITM attack risk, etc.  Mint's website had a similar type of 'breach' happen a few years back, and it pointed people to malicious downloads.  Original Mint users though prior to the compromise and after the remediation of the compromise and everything was back 'secure' would have been shielded from 'bad signatures on packages' wityh the keysigs when they start getting "BADSIG" errors

Comment: "Am I missing something here?" – Yes: you should always verify the fingerprint of a public signing key using a separate path of information that cannot possibly be compromised by an attacker. For example, in my university, the fingerprints of all important keys were displayed on a large poster at the IT support helpdesk, were posted at the student registration center at the beginning of the semester, were printed in the back of every issue of the monthly IT magazine, were available as paper copies from the IT helpdesk, and were handed out to every new student joining the university.

Comment: My local computer club used to publish their fingerprints in the local newspaper and also read them out on the local student radio station. There were strict instructions to any new student, to use one of those paper copies to verify the fingerprint of any SSH or signing key before accepting it.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag, that completes the puzzle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is for multiple reasons, and they all revolve around [Man In The Middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (MITM) - specifically, protecting you from any case in the future where you get hit with an MITM attack or some other kind of malicious redirect to 'false download sources' *after* you've gotten the good key.

---

If you're in the situation that's worst case - your system is already compromised and redirected to a bad site for a malicious actor ("MA" for short) - then you're hosed, and this doesn't protect you because you'll be downloading MA's keys.  That's not the point of this protection of the PGP key and keyring here, it's to protect you from *future* MITM attacks.

At this example, you're already compromised, and what key is in use is irrelevant because MA likely has control of your computer, network, data, etc. at this point.  The most common protection scenario however is you *start* with a clean environment/system and *then* install software from the legitimate source. (see next section)

---

However, starting from a compromised environment isn't the 'common scenario' here that key sigs protect against.  The most common scenarion is: uou are on a clean system, with clean updates, no compromise on your system, the DNS servers you use, the network you're connected to, etc.

You go to install Docker and get the Docker key from the real Docker website.  You then install Docker, and the key validates.

At some point in the future, MA has taken control of how your traffic flows to the Internet and redirected you to a 'fake' Docker download site.

Unless MA has stolen the PGP key from Docker with its corresponding private key, your `apt` system will show that the signatures on `download.docker.com` **do not match** and that something odd is going on in your environment and won't apply the updates from MA's 'bad' repository redirect.

**This** is what the keysigning and key parts protect against: you being MITM'd in the *future*.  It doesn't protect you if you're already compromised, nothing will.  It protects you when you start clean and uncompromised and then *become* compromised for some reason.

This is also why you should verify the keys fingerprints against known good key fingerprints.  Most of the good providers of repositories have their fingerprints readily available for validation manually so that you are not relying on JUST commands to get and trust the keys.